# finding the height of the document resulting from styling xml with xsl in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xslt

I've used the example from w3 school's website here: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp

I've used the example under the heading: Transforming XML to XHTML in the Browser.

Here, variables "ex" and "resultDocument" are the result of using xsl to transform an xml.

What I would like to know, is if there is a way to read the height of this resulting document?

I ultimately need to put the content inside an iframe and need to know the height in order to make the frame the right size.

Any help/pointers appreciated. Thanks

edit: also, how is it possible to update the contents of the iframe with "ex" or "resultDocument"?

2nd edit: I've managed to update contents of iframe with `$('#box').contents().find('html').html(resultDocument);`
I've searched high and low though and still unable to find a solution for finding the height of the body of resultDocument in a cross-browser compatible method though and still nothing. Anybody please help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect()
```

after the transformations.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, that will return the values of the html body of "this" document that the iframe is nested in, rather than the html body of ex or resultDocument,

how would I get the height of these? is it somehting like:
`var rect = resultDocument.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
 var h = rect.bottom - rect.top;
 console.log(h);`

Comment: The method returns the values of the element on which it is called, so just  call it on your necessary element and you'll get what you need. Though I'm not sure it will work in older IEs. Maybe yourElement.scrollHeight is safer.

Comment: sorry I'm confused, resultDocument.scrollHeight returns undefined

Comment: And what does resultDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight say?

Comment: Chrome console brings upUncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined

Comment: `document.documentElement.scrollHeight;`
returns the height of the main html page where I make my function calls, so setting the iframe height to this is wrong. How can I find the equivalent height of the document which I am placing in the iframe? - which is resultDocument??

Comment: it doesn't seems as though you can make any of the normal DOM functions on this object resultDocument